# How do I delay html text from appearing until background image sprite is loaded?

Tags: jquery, css, load, window, background-image

Here's some sample code that I want to control using jQuery (white button bg on black page bg):

```
    <ul class="buttons">
        <li class="button-displays"><a href="/products/">Products and Services for the company</a></li>
        <li class="button-packaging"><a href="/packaging/">Successful packaging services for the company</a></li>
        <li class="button-tools"><a href="/tools/">Data, mail and print tools for your company</li>
    </ul>
```

In the CSS file, I have the following:

```
    .buttons li { background-image: url(images/sprite.png); height:126px; width:293px; float:left; margin:0 0 0 9px; }
    .button-displays { background-position: 0 125px; }
    .button-packaging { background-position: 0 250px; }
    .button-tools { background-position: 0 375px; }
```

I have styled these list items to look like clickable buttons with the background sprite helping to fill out the background of the buttons.

My client doesn't like that in Firefox and Safari, when the page loads for the first time, the text inside the anchor loads first then the background sprite of the li (which is around 150kb b/c I have a total of 6 buttons) loads only when the sprite is fully downloaded. The background suddenly appears after a couple of seconds of downloading leaving the text in the anchor by itself until the background pops in.

I have tried playing with the following code in hopes that it would delay the loading of this markup and CSS:

```
    $('.buttons li a').load(function() {
    });
```

and

```
    $(window).load(function() {
        $(.buttons);
    });
```

I do not understand jQuery enough to know if this forces the code to wait until all elements load before appearing. I'd rather force the list item elements in the buttons code to delay appearing on the page until the bg img sprite is completely loaded.

Thanks for your help and suggestions!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think you can attach a load event specifically for background images.

Try this instead:

Make the `.button li` elements `display:none`:

```
.buttons li { display:none; background-image: url(images/sprite.png); height:126px; width:293px; float:left; margin:0 0 0 9px; }
```

Then in your jQuery, create an image with the URL of your sprite, and attach a `load` handler to it that will show the buttons.

```
$(function() {
      // create a dummy image
    var img = new Image();

      // give it a single load handler
    $(img).one('load',function() {
        $('.buttons li').fadeIn(); // fade in the elements when the image loads
    });

      // give it the src of your background image
    img.src = "images/sprite.png";

      // make sure if fires in case it was cached
    if( img.complete )
        $(img).load();
});
```

Comment: I'm not sure this method is much better b/c initially display:none breaks my layout in this area then when the sprite loads it will suddenly jump the layout to be correct. I did try it, however, and nothing happened.

Comment: @Micah, then use visibility instead of display, and set it with `.css('visibility','visible')` instead of `.fadeIn()`. Should work. Worked fine in my test.

Comment: ...[here's a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/gYSa2/1/). I used a generic image, and added an `alert()` so you can see that it does fire.

Comment: Safari Web Inspector is giving me an error when I use this code: _Result of expression '$' [undefined] is not a function_.

Comment: @Micah: Then it would seem that you're running the code before you have jQuery loaded.

Comment: I'm using Wordpress and jQuery CDN is loading in 'wp_head'. Just after wp_head I have the 'script' tag containing your code modified for the site. So, at least linearly, it's loading after the jQuery file.

Comment: @Micah: What happens if you do `alert(jQuery.fn.jquery)` in the first line of your code? Also, if `$` is undefined, then replace each instance of `$` in the code with the full `jQuery`.

Comment: It spits back 1.4.4 before the page even loads.

Comment: @Micah: Then see the update to my comment above. Could be that `$` is getting released. Use `jQuery` instead of `$` and see if it works.

Comment: Yes, replacing `$` with `jQuery` fixed the problem, but why?! I have another script file loading in the footer containing lots of `$` with no problem.

Comment: @Micah: Could be that the other script is explicitly defining `$` to reference jQuery. In the first line of your script, before you reference `$`, do this: `var $ = jQuery.noConflict()` and the `$` should work. Better, wrap the script content in `(function($) { /* the script content */ })(jQuery);` This will make a local variable reference to `$` pointing to jQuery.

Comment: Interesting, the `noConflict()` made it work, but just adding that line means more unnecessary code. It's just easier to write `jQuery' instead of `$`.  Thanks for all of your help; this gets me a little closer to understanding what I'm doing with jQuery!

Comment: @Micah: You're welcome. Regarding noConflict, it depends on how many times you need to type out `jQuery`. If there's not that many, then not a big deal. If there are several, you'll reduce your code with the shortcut.

Answer (score 3):

I think you're on the right track.  JQuery's load function executes after the element selected has completely finished loading - meaning all content is downloaded.  The thing is with your code, the button markup will download before the content is downloaded.  So, you can use jQuery to reveal the buttons completely with a load event.  So, set you're buttons to be hidden in your CSS (visibility:hidden).  Then, use you're $(document).load(function(){}) to reveal the buttons:

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $('.button').css({visibility: 'visible'});
})
```

Comment: Yep. patrick's correct.  Should be 'window' instead of 'document'.  (Code updated)

Comment: This method just worked but I had to replace `$` with `jQuery` in order to make it work, similar to the method above. Why is this?

Answer (score 0):

write you code inside

```
$(document).ready(function(){

//your logic here 

});
```

this makes sure that your DOM manipulation starts after your DOM is fully loded...

plus you can also use

```
$("#yourDOMelementID").ready(function(){

});
```

to make sure that the intended element is ready to be manipulated...

more over to delay an event handler your can use [`.setTimeOut()`](http://stuntsnippets.com/jquery-settimeout/) or in some cases [`.delay()`](http://api.jquery.com/delay/)

Comment: .ready() is the wrong function.  It'll fire after the markup is loaded but before the binary data is downloaded.  .load() is the method to use.

Answer (score 0):

Set the buttons to be hidden initially, then do the jquery [load](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/) on the li, since that is what has the background image applied:

```
$('.buttons li').load(function() {
        $('.buttons').show();
    });
```