# jQuery delay until background image is loaded, then faded in?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I've been doing alot of research and there are loads of plugins and tutorials out there that cover the use of large background images.  Unfortunately, they all have one thing in common - they use absolutely positioned images to behave as "fake" background images.

Normally that would work fine for me and I've done that before, however, this project has a repeating background image, so it's necessary that I use normal CSS rules to declare the background image.

All of that being said, is there a way to check to see if the image is loaded and tell jQuery to fade this background image in once it is loaded? The main thing I'm looking for is a way for jQuery to verify that the image is actually loaded.  If not, then I suppose I need to settle for a simple static delay (which unfortunately ruins the effect for users who have slow connections).

Last thing - can this be done via CSS class switching/toggling so that I can change the body class before and after the image is loaded?  This would be a fallback for users without javascript and would make it so I don't have to `.hide()` my entire body while the background image loads.

***EDIT: This thread seems to have a similar discussion but I don't think it's quite the same thing: [How do I delay html text from appearing until background image sprite is loaded?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4937127/how-do-i-delay-html-text-from-appearing-until-background-image-sprite-is-loaded) ***

*** EDIT 2 ***

Looks like the above thread worked after all, except I'm still missing the fadeIn effect. I set the fadeIn intentionally high and it's not animating for some reason, any ideas why?

```
<script>

$(function() {
      // create a dummy image
    var img = new Image();

      // give it a single load handler
    $(img).one('load',function() {
        $('html').css('background','url(<?php bloginfo( 'template_url' ); ?>/images/red_curtain.jpg) top center repeat-y').fadeIn(12000); // fade in the elements when the image loads
    });

      // declare background image source
    img.src = "<?php bloginfo( 'template_url' ); ?>/images/red_curtain.jpg";

      // make sure if fires in case it was cached
    if( img.complete )
        $(img).load();
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems an old thread but I found a solution for this.
Hope it can help:

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $('<img/>').attr('src', 'images/imgsrc.png').load(function() {
        $('#loading').fadeOut(500);     
    $('#wrapper').fadeIn(200);
});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use $(document).load() to achieve what you want.

"I set the fadeIn intentionally high and it's not animating for some reason, any ideas why?"

It is, just before the page has loaded

Comment: Any idea how I could achieve the effect via a switch of body class?  I'd like it to degrade gracefully (e.g. class for the body is not switched for users who have javascript disabled)

Answer (score 1):

Add `display: none;` to your body tag

```
<body style="display: none">
```

Then with jQuery modify your code so it looks like this:

```
$(img).load(function(){
  $("body").show();
});
```

Now page content will only show after img loading is complete.

Comment: This is good, but I want to do this with class switching so that I don't screw over people who don't have javascript enabled.

Comment: I don't understand..You are already using javaScript in your question above. jQuery is javaScript.

Answer (score 0):

To check when the image is loaded, declare another, "regular" image (i.e. the `<img>` tag) with the same `src` and attach event handler to it. Browser won't load the same image twice, so that event will also mean that the background is loaded.

Another trick I can propose is to go back to "fake" background. In order to make it "tile", you can create an `iframe`, stretched to cover the whole body, and having that image as background, and then fade that iframe as you like, while the rest of the page remains safely in the "main" frame.