# Delaying loading of resources

Tags: javascript, resources, load

**My question** is, is there a way to first let the website display and then load those heavy resources using JavaScript whilst preserving functionality in case JavaScript is not available?

**My reason:** I'm trying to optimize my Joomla template. There could be some pretty heavy resources like oversized background images. My test case features a 4000px*3000px 3.01MB .png picture. Although SO showed me [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210028/jquery-delay-until-background-image-is-loaded-then-faded-in) solution, I cannot use it since I plan to use the background-image even if there is no JavaScript. Plus I would have come up with that myself...

*It would make things a lot easier if somebody could give me solid proof that nearly all Internet users use JavaScript... I'm talking about 99.999%.*

Regardless, this has some impact on the total time until the website is displayed. There is another resource that I'd like to use this technique on, which is a PHP script run by a Joomla plugin taking 1 second to respond, also impacting the total time.

**Ultimately I'd like to control when specific resources are loaded.**

**My own attempt:** I thought of removing the `background-image` style of related elements, but my timeline still didn't change. It renders a lot quicker since the browser has less work to do, but still the picture is being loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add a swap a class on the `<html>` tag using JS like [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) does (it swaps `.no-js` for `.js` then you can selectively add images for browsers that don't have JS enabled.

Then you can happily create a new `Image` object, load it and change the elements style when it's ready.

Comment: I'm already using such a mechanism to enhance the design of my website. But I didn't think of applying it to the `<html>` tag yet... I tried it and it worked, I can definitely work with that. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 1):

I guess you should reconsider your case. Why would you like to load such a heavy image on the site in the first place? What about those mobile users with expensive data plans? Are you sure that they will want to spend 3mb for a 4k image?

Maybe not.

Instead, did you try to optimise your image for the web? Softwares such as photoshop give such an option. What about adaptive images as part of a responsive design? (smashing magazine had a nice article about that not a while ago http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2013/06/02/clown-car-technique-solving-for-adaptive-images-in-responsive-web-design/)

If you insist however, there are a few javascript libraries that will help you out. first one that comes in my mind is backstretch (http://srobbin.com/jquery-plugins/backstretch/). It will display a default colour in your background, until your images load and then it swaps them.

Comment: It's just a test case. Of course the image was going to be optimized and definitely downscaled. For mobile users I even had a different layout in mind, in terms of responsive design. I'd use a subdomain particularly for mobile devices if I can't manage to find a sophisticated solution integrated in the default website. Anyways, thanks for the concern and article, I'll look through it.